# Unable to pass the ec2-instance details while creating AWS network load balancer using AWS CDK for python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk, nlb

I am trying to create two EC2 instances and a Network load balancer using python for AWS-CDK. I am unable to pass in the target type details which are the above two instances while creating the NLB target group. In short, I need to create EC2 instances and attach a network load balance along with it. Please refer to the below code.

```
from aws_cdk import core 
from aws_cdk import aws_ec2 as ec2
from aws_cdk import aws_elasticloadbalancingv2 as elb
from aws_cdk import aws_elasticloadbalancingv2_targets as targets
from cdk_splunk_servers.myconstants import *


 class CdkDeploymentStack(core.Stack):

   def __init__(
    self,
    scope: core.Construct,
    construct_id: str,
    env_vars,
    inbound_rules,
    **kwargs
) -> None:
    super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

    myvpc = ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(self, "myvpc", vpc_name=env_vars["vpc_name"])

    ### Create the security group with required ingress rules
    ec2_sg = ec2.SecurityGroup(self, "sg-splunk", vpc=myvpc)
    core.Tags.of(ec2_sg).add("Name", ec2_sg.node.path)

    # Add the required inbound rules to the security group
    for rule in inbound_rules:
        peer = ec2.Peer.ipv4(rule["source"])
        if rule["protocol"] == "tcp":
            if rule["portRange"] == "":
                connection = ec2.Port.tcp(rule["port"])
            else:
                portRange = rule["portRange"].split("-")
                if portRange.__len__() != 2:
                    print("Port range should be in format startport-endport")
                print(dir(ec2.Port))
                connection = ec2.Port.tcp_range(
                    int(portRange[0]), int(portRange[1])
                )
        elif rule["protocol"] == "udp":
            if rule["portRange"] == "":
                connection = ec2.Port.udp(rule["port"])
            else:
                portRange = rule["portRange"].split("-")
                if portRange.__len__() != 2:
                    print("Port range should be in format startport-endport")
                connection = ec2.Port.udp_range(
                    int(portRange[0]), int(portRange[1])
                )
        description = rule["description"]
        ec2_sg.add_ingress_rule(
            peer=peer, connection=connection, description=description
        )
    
    ### Create EC2 instance for Deployment servers
    deployment_01 = ec2.CfnInstance(
        self,
        env_vars["deployment_server_name1"],
        block_device_mappings=[
            ec2.CfnInstance.BlockDeviceMappingProperty(
                device_name="/dev/sda1",
                ebs=ec2.CfnInstance.EbsProperty(
                    delete_on_termination=False, encrypted=True, volume_size=env_vars["deployment_root_volume"]
                ),
            ),
            ec2.CfnInstance.BlockDeviceMappingProperty(
                device_name="/dev/sdb",
                ebs=ec2.CfnInstance.EbsProperty(
                    delete_on_termination=False, encrypted=True, volume_size=env_vars["deployment_user_volume1"]
                ),
            ),
            ec2.CfnInstance.BlockDeviceMappingProperty(
                device_name="/dev/sdc",
                ebs=ec2.CfnInstance.EbsProperty(
                    delete_on_termination=False, encrypted=True, volume_size=env_vars["deployment_user_volume2"]
                ),
            )
        ],
        ebs_optimized=True,
        image_id=env_vars["ami_id_rhel"],
        instance_type=env_vars["instance_type_dep"],
        key_name=env_vars["key_pair_name"],
        security_group_ids=[ec2_sg.security_group_id],
        subnet_id=env_vars["general_subnet1"]
    )
    deployment_02 = ec2.CfnInstance(
        self,
        env_vars["deployment_server_name2"],
        block_device_mappings=[
           ec2.CfnInstance.BlockDeviceMappingProperty(
                device_name="/dev/sda1",
                ebs=ec2.CfnInstance.EbsProperty(
                    delete_on_termination=False, encrypted=True, volume_size=env_vars["deployment_root_volume"]
                ),
            ),
            ec2.CfnInstance.BlockDeviceMappingProperty(
                device_name="/dev/sdb",
                ebs=ec2.CfnInstance.EbsProperty(
                    delete_on_termination=False, encrypted=True, volume_size=env_vars["deployment_user_volume1"]
                ),
            ),
            ec2.CfnInstance.BlockDeviceMappingProperty(
                device_name="/dev/sdc",
                ebs=ec2.CfnInstance.EbsProperty(
                    delete_on_termination=False, encrypted=True, volume_size=env_vars["deployment_user_volume2"]
                ),
            )
        ],
        ebs_optimized=True,
        image_id=env_vars["ami_id_rhel"],
        instance_type=env_vars["instance_type_dep"],
        key_name=env_vars["key_pair_name"],
        security_group_ids=[ec2_sg.security_group_id],
        subnet_id=env_vars["general_subnet2"]
    )

   
    myvpc = ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(
        self,
        "SecurityVpc",
        vpc_name=env_vars["vpc_name"],
    )

    subnet_id_1 = env_vars["general_subnet1"]
    subnet_id_2 = env_vars["general_subnet2"]

    # Import the corresponding subnets into CDK
    subnet_1 = ec2.Subnet.from_subnet_id(
        self, id="elbsubnet1", subnet_id=subnet_id_1
    )
    subnet_2 = ec2.Subnet.from_subnet_id(
        self, id="elbsubnet2", subnet_id=subnet_id_2
    )

    ### NLB creation in security account
    nlb_security_deployment_server = elb.NetworkLoadBalancer(
        self,
        env_vars["nlb_name"],
        cross_zone_enabled= True,
        vpc=myvpc,
        vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(subnets=[subnet_1, subnet_2]),
        internet_facing=False,
        load_balancer_name=env_vars["nlb_name"],
    )

    # Add a listener on a particular port
    listener_security_deployment_server1 = nlb_security_deployment_server.add_listener(
        "listener1", port=LISTENER_PORT1
    )
    listener_security_deployment_server2 = nlb_security_deployment_server.add_listener(
        "listener2", port=LISTENER_PORT2
    )

    listener_security_deployment_server1.add_targets(
        "tg1-deployment-server-security",
        port=LISTENER_PORT1,
        target_group_name="tg1-deployment-server-security",
        targets=[
            targets.InstanceTarget(
                #NEED HELP HERE
                instance=deployment01,
                port=TARGET_PORT1, 
            ),
            targets.InstanceTarget(
                instance=deployment01,
                port=TARGET_PORT2,
            )
        ],
    )
    listener_security_deployment_server2.add_targets(
        "tg2-deployment-server-security",
        port=LISTENER_PORT2,
        target_group_name="tg2-deployment-server-security",
        targets=[
            targets.InstanceTarget(
                instance=deployment_02,
                port=TARGET_PORT1,
            ),
            targets.InstanceTarget(
                instance=deployment_02,
                port=TARGET_PORT2,
            )
        ],
    )

    core.Tags.of(deployment_01).add("Name", deployment_01.node.path)
    core.Tags.of(deployment_02).add("Name", deployment_02.node.path)

    ### Common Tagging
    core.Tags.of(self).add("Project", PROJECT)
    core.Tags.of(self).add("Environment", env_vars["env_name"])
    core.Tags.of(self).add("CostCenter", COST_CENTER)
    core.Tags.of(self).add("LineOfBusiness", LINE_OF_BUSINESS)
    core.Tags.of(self).add("Owner", OWNER)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you’re mixing L1 and L2 constructs. So if you use ec2.Instance (L2 construct) rather than ec2.CfnInstance (L1 construct) this should work.